# Git alias revision

Tags: git

Is it possible to alias a revision `HEAD` into something shorter like eg. `H`?
May seem like a worthless improvement but I type that really often in my workflow.

I can imagine using shell features to do that but I'm curious if it's possible in plain git commandline.

Comment: Since Gt version 1.8.5, you can write `@` instead of `HEAD` anywhere. (Note that `@{1}` and `HEAD@{1}` are different though, you need `@@{1}` to mean `HEAD@{1}`.)

Comment: that's certainly helpful and solves most of my issues. However it would be nice to know if that type of alias can be made by ourselves.

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is yes *if* you have a sufficiently programmable shell (e.g., bash). Then you can do anything you want, by taking over the [read-eval-print loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)—entirely, or just at certain points—and doing arbitrary substitutions. But then you must write a fair bit of code, and get it right lest you break your ability to do anything at all. :-)